# Не отображаются кнопки в яндексовском блоке «Поделиться»

Tags: javascript, html

Я работаю в dreaweaver. Вставила скрипты и блок кнопок. В просмотре на консоле все как надо. Загружаю сайт и вижу только мою "рамочку" от того места, где должен быть блок соц.кнопок.

Так это выглядит в коде:

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="blockabs1">
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,linkedin,lj"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: в классе `blockabs1` что указано у вас? И скрипт как вставили? Код вставки скрипта посмотрите. Пути проверьте. особенно на сервере.

Comment: blockabs1 всего лишь определяет место размещения и тень.".blockabs1 
{
    position : absolute;
    top  : 20px;
    left: 985px;
 padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
 align-content: center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(128, 0, 0, 1);
}" Скрипт вставила тупо перед своим блоком."<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
    <div class="blockabs1">
     <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,linkedin,lj"></div>
    </div>"